# How to make Windows 7 log off from Samba shared drive (manually or automatically)

Tags: windows-7

How do I make Windows 7 log off from a password-protected Samba network drive?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open CMD, type `NET USE X: /DELETE` or `NET USE \\SERVER\SHARENAME /DELETE`

where `X:` is your drive and `\\SERVER\SHARENAME` your fully qualified share name.

### Step by Step

1. View all network connections:

   ```
   NET USE
   ```

   **Example Output:**

   ```
     Status                 Local       Remote            Network
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   OK                                 \\name\IPC$       Microsoft Windows Network
   OK                                 \\name2\folder    Microsoft Windows Network
   ```
2. Using the Remote name, we can disconnect using on of the following statements, depending on which one we want to disconnect from:

   ```
   net use \\name /delete
   ```

   OR

   ```
   net use \\name2\folder /delete
   ```

   **Example Output:** (given the above `\\name\IPC` being connected))

   ```
   Net use  \\name /delete
   \\name was deleted successfully.
   ```

Another way, to disconnect from *every* share is to execute `net use * /delete`. This will disconnect every Network share you're currently connected to. This is still quicker than logging off and back on.

If you want to create an icon to *automatically* disconnect *all* network shares (using a GUI method), you can do the following:

1. Right-click on a blank area of the folder you want to add the shortcut to.
2. Point to **New**->**Shortcut** and click.
3. Type `net use * /delete /y` for the **Command**, then click **Next**.
4. Give it a name, and click **Finish**.

You can also specify a certain network share, if known in advance, and use that one instead. Using the `/y` automatically select the `yes` option in the command.

Answer (score 5):

### open notepad:

```
@echo off
::Disconnect user
net use * /delete /y
msg * /time:5 "You have been successfully Disconnected"
```

---

Copy paste save as a bat (file Extention " *.bat ", create a shortcut edit the shortcut to an icon of your choosing...

upon double click, the command will be run and a gui popup box will say the message and go away in 5 seconds or wait 5 seconds till appearing...

we use this quite a bit at work :)

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.